# Comunicação entre aplicações usando socket através de UDP fazendo Multicast

Tags: delphi, socket

Estou tentando fazer a comunicação entre aplicações onde uma delas transmite uma determinada mensagem e as outras apenas recebem, não conheço o endereço IP das que irão receber e nem mesmo se estarão lá para receber a mensagem, apenas preciso fazer um *multicast* na rede.

Estou usando a Ararat Synapse com a classe `TUDPBlockSocket` e achei o seguinte exemplo no site do componente...

Recebimento da mensagem

```
procedure TForm1.btnReceberClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   rcvsock:TUDPBlockSocket;
   buf:string;
begin
  rcvsock:=TUDPBlockSocket.Create;
  try
    rcvsock.createsocket;
    rcvsock.Bind('0.0.0.0','22401');
    rcvsock.AddMulticast('234.5.6.7');
    buf:=rcvsock.RecvPacket(60000);
    showmessage(buf);
  finally
    rcvsock.free;
  end;
end;
```

Envio da mensagem

```
procedure TForm1.btnEnviarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sndsock:TUDPBlockSocket;
begin
  sndsock:=TUDPBlockSocket.Create;
  try
    sndsock.createsocket;
    sndsock.Bind('0.0.0.0','0');
    sndsock.MulticastTTL := 1;
    sndsock.connect('234.5.6.7','22401');
    sndsock.SendString('Ahoy!'+CRLF);
  finally
    sndsock.free;
  end;
end;
```

Isso tudo funciona bem se abrir apenas 2 instâncias do aplicativo e na primeira clicar bo botão `btnReceber` e na segunda clicar no botão `btnEnviar`. No entanto se abro 3 instâncias, uma enviando e as outras duas recebendo apenas uma delas recebe e a outra fica lá parada aguardando os 60000 milissegundos. O teste com apenas duas instâncias funciona apenas se as duas estiverem sendo executadas no mesmo micro, inclusive já verifiquei se o meu roteador estava com o IGMP habilitado para permitir o *multicast*, mas mesmo assim não funcionou pela rede.

Estou usando Delphi XE e fiz testes no Windows XP em uma VM com Virtual Box e também em um micro com Windows 7.

Comment: Faz muito tempo (mesmo) que não programo em Delphi, então nem me arrisco a uma resposta. Mas talvez o problema esteja no `bind` usando `0.0.0.0`. Você tentou usar o endereço externo da sua interface de rede? Essa thread pode ajudar a entender o que eu quero dizer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556811/why-bind-a-socket-to-an-address

Comment: Precisa mesmo de multicast? Se for na mesma subnet bastaria usar broadcast simples de UDP (endereço 192.168.0.255 numa rede 192.168.0.0/24, por exemplo, ou 10.255.255.255 numa rede 10.0.0.0/8)

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Não sei muito de delphi mas já trabalhei bastante com multicast em C então vou dar meu pitaco...

Você está testando com 3 instâncias na mesma máquina? Como você fez para as duas instâncias cliente fazerem o "bind" na mesma porta? A segunda deveria dar algum erro no bind (algo do tipo "address already in use") já que normalmente você não tem 2 processos "ouvindo" uma mesma porta.

Seria útil testar o retorno da função bind() para ver se ela realmente funcionou.

Comment: Realmente você tem razão, fiz o teste verificando o LastError do socket e ele mostrou "Address already in use".  Em um multicast não seria normal mais de um processo ouvir a mesma porta? Também testei com uma instância em cada micro mas ai nem funcionou, ou seja, a instância ouvindo a porta não chegou a receber a mensagem, verifiquei o roteador e o IGMP estava habilitado, tem ideia do que posso ser?

Comment: Não tenho certeza já que sempre uso em mas de uma máquina mas a opção SO_REUSEPORT do setsockopt devem ajudar. Outra idéia seria usar um sniffer como o wireshark para confirmar se o pacote está saíndo para a rede e com os endereços corretos.

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar os componentes da Indy como o TIdUDPServer e o TIdUDPClient

no recebimento você trata assim:

```
procedure TMainHost.UDPServer2UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  AData: TBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
//

//onde AData é o recebimento em bytes... 
//Você pode tratar os caracteres e montar sua mensagem com o Chr...

end;
```

no envio você trata assim por exemplo:

```
function TMainHost.DoSendModificarCamera(
  aCamera: TCameraJSONRecognized): Integer;
var
  strTemp: String;
begin


  strTemp := 'string de envio';

  try

    IdUDPClient1.Host := '255.255.255.255';
    IdUDPClient1.Port := 34567;
    IdUDPServer2.Active := False;
    IdUDPServer2.DefaultPort := 34567;
    IdUDPClient1.Active := True;
    IdUDPClient1.Send(strTemp);
    IdUDPClient1.Active := False;
    IdUDPServer2.Active := True;
    Result := Length(x);
  except
    Result := -Length(x);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Fiz o teste como você sugeriu, embora este modo me pareça ser um brodcast. Tive alguns problemas com o evento Read do UDP Server e o Delphi XE mas consegui contornar. O problema e que ao tentar enviar a mensagem (usando duas instÂncias no mesmo micro) ocorre o erro 10013, já desativei o firewaal mas não resolveu (não tem anti virus rodando). Tem ideia de como contornar este problema?

Comment: Isso não está acontecendo porque você está usando duas instâncias UDP com a mesma porta não? Por exemplo um Server usando essa porta e um Client tentando conectar ao servidor pela mesma porta no mesmo PC? Tenta rodar o server em uma outra máquina e mandar uma mensagem para ele... porque me parece ser isso, o uso de dois aplicativos na mesma porta...

Comment: Não, a mensagem de erro 10013 ocorre mesmo executando uma instância em cada micro com firewall desativado.